# Is there a way to create a for loop with only two expressions in C?

Tags: c, for-loop

I came across this in the C standard text, any version I can find for C99 or C11, at §6.8.5 :

```
iteration-statement:
  while ( expression ) statement
  do statement while ( expression ) ;
  for ( expression ; expression ; expression ) statement
  for ( declaration expression ;  expression ) statement
```

The fourth item here seems to be a `for` with only one semicolon, and I don't see any reference to this syntax anywhere else. Can anyone here explain what am I missing?

Comment: That does not seem to compile either. Maybe it was a typo and they meant to have an extra semicolon after, with no body?

Comment: @merlin2011 : and noone noticed for over ten years, typo finding its way into C11 ?

Comment: Looks like you discovered it finally... :-)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The production for `declaration` is:

> declaration:
>       declaration-specifiers init-declarator-list<sub>opt</sub> **;**

So the semicolon is already part of it.

Comment: seems like OP missed (or forgot) this small thing... :) +1!!

Comment: Great, yes, I missed this small thing! Thanks! Nice find nwellnhof

Comment: Oh wait, so I can use a `static_assert-declaration` in a for loop? It is in the Syntax of declaration in C11.

Comment: @BuellaGábor Oh, that's interesting. GCC accepts it, clang rejects it as a syntax error (which it isn't). IMO, it's unclear whether the constraint "The declaration part of a `for` statement shall only declare identifiers for objects having storage class `auto` or `register`." is meant to disallow that, but it seems to me like it is meant to do so (even if it fails to *actually* do so).