# Alternative for-loop syntax

Tags: c, for-loop, language-lawyer

Below is a snippet of the C standard(section 6.8.5 of the [n1256](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) TC3 C99).

> *iteration-statement:*
>       **while** **(** *expression* **)** *statement*
>       **do** *statement* **while** **(** *expression* **)** ;
>       **for** **(** *expression<sub>opt</sub>* ; *expression<sub>opt</sub>* ; *expression<sub>opt</sub>* **)** *statement*
>       **for** **(** *declaration* *expression<sub>opt</sub>* ; *expression<sub>opt</sub>* **)** *statement*

What piques my interest is the last statement: `for ( declaration expression ; expression ) statement`. 6.8.5.1 explains the `for` loop, but only mentions the `for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement` syntax.

I did a few attempts at writing code according to this syntax, but they all gave me syntax errors. Examples:

```
for (int i = 0, i; i++) { /* ... */ }
for (int i = 0; !(i++)) { /* ... */ }
```

Which all results in errors similar to `error: expected ‘;’ before ‘)’ token` when compiled using GCC(v4.9.2).

I'm not sure if I'm interpreting the standard in the right way. Can this syntax be used in some useful way, or have I overlooked something?

Comment: I really wondered what a *declaration expression* wouldd be before reading the answers :-)

Comment: this is exactly the same question as: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23168997/is-there-a-way-to-create-a-for-loop-with-only-two-expressions-in-c

Answer (score 30, accepted):

If you see, the syntax is,

```
 for ( declaration expression1opt ; expression2opt ) statement
```

Let's compare it with a general statement

```
 for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) printf("%d \t", i);
```

Here,

- `int i = 0;` denotes `declaration` [includes the `;`]
- `i < 10` denotes `expression1opt` [optional]
- `;` is as per the syntax requirement of `;` [must, as described in syntax]
- `i++` is the `expression2opt` [optional]
- `printf("%d \t", i);` is the `statement`

Now, in your case,

```
for (int i = 0, i; i++) { /* ... */ }
```

- `int i = 0, i;` denotes `declaration`
- `i++` denotes `expression1opt`
- `;` is *missing* .....

The last point here produces the error. You need to have the `;` to pass the syntax check.

Comment: and the reason for the downvote?

Comment: I guess that the downvote was because this answer doesn't explain anything. It basically says "syntax is invalid; try something else", while OP wanted to know *why* it's invalid.

Comment: @anatolyg ok sir, so what more I need to add . can you please suggest?

Comment: When you say that in some code something is optional, and the code itself contains a syntax error, I don't understand what you say. Also, what does "terminate" mean for expressions?

Comment: @anatolyg I think that's the reason. nevertheless, I expectd that comment from the downvoter him/her self. Thank you for taking your time to make me understand the mistake. maybe I should have chosen a better set of words. :-)

Comment: It's very clear now!

Comment: Very good answer. Even more comprehensive than the initial accepted answer. This answer deserves the acceptance mark!

Answer (score 40):

Unfortunately, this is not easy to read. You are misreading the second case of the `for` statement. The first semicolon is an integral part of `declaration` and thus hidden to your eyes. You can easily check such syntax questions by looking into Annex A. There you have:

```
(6.7) declaration: 
    declaration-specifiers init-declarator-listopt ;
    static_assert-declaration
```

Comment: wow, this is confusing without proper context.

Comment: Thanks for the advice on using the standard. So, actually, the `for` loop that most people use nowadays (`for(int i=0;i<10;i++)`) is what I thought was the 'alternative'? Could you explain me the difference between the two iteration statements? I'd really appreciate it if you expand on that.

Comment: BTW this issue is explained alittle in the C++ standard (draft [here](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2013/n3690.pdf); look in section 6.5)

Comment: @BennoZeeman, from my experience it is unfortunately not the `for`-loop with declaration that is used by most people. The difference is the scope of the variable, if you restrict it to the `for` loop generally the code is cleaner and you don't have to watch whether or not you are polluting future uses of an iteration variable with old values. This reduces code complexity for you as a future reader and for the compiler.

Comment: @Jens Gustedt Thanks a lot. That cleared it up for me. Perhaps you can edit that explanation into your answer? I think people can benefit from that.