# Syntactical Sour

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax, standards

Well there are just some weird syntax question thrown to you by some author of the books just to check the understanding of the syntax while I think these kind of weird syntax may not be used by any programmer but just for the sake of understanding, I would like to understand how the following for loop behaves and why the compiler doesn't throws any syntactical error

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    short int i=0;
    for(i<=5&&i>=-1 ;++i; i>0)
      printf("%d",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The for statement has the following form :

```
for(expression; expression; expression);
```

The three expressions can be any valid expressions allowed in the C language.
So the code is syntactically valid. However due to uninitialized variable, the behaviour will be undefined. Also, it is advisable to use `int main(void)` and return an exit code.

Starting with C99 and C11, declarations are also allowed in place of the first expressions making it a statement. Thus it is :

```
for(statement; expression; expression);
```

Comment: The post was edited by OP. Should I edit the answer too?

Comment: Ugh. Let's just note here that it was originally just `short int i;` and be done with it.

Comment: So in the for loop we can write the initialization, conditional and updation expression in any order it doesn't matter rt ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja: Of course it matters! If it didn't, how would the compiler know which is which?

Comment: ^Yes we can write it in any order. The middle expression decides when the loop terminates (if at all).

Comment: Aren't the first (and maybe third) part statements, not just expressions ? You can write declarations within.

Comment: C99 and C11 allows declaration of variables too. I dont think that was supported in C89.

Answer (score 2):

For loops are:

```
for( run_this_once_at_start;  check_this_each_time;  run_this_after_each_iteration)
```

The actual code in those three areas can be any expression at all so long as the second one is a expression that's a valid operand for the `!` operator.    The first one can even contain a declaration, in C99 and later.

In your example there are no syntax errors. The first and third conditions don't do what would be considered good style, however they are not illegal.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, as per the `for` loop is concerned, the *simplified* syntax <sup>#</sup> is

```
for( run_this_once_at_start;  check_this_each_time;  run_this_after_each_iteration)
```

<sup>Credit: Mr. Matt</sup>

Compiler will only check for the matching syntax. Let's compare it with your code, which says

```
for(i<=5&&i>=-1 ;++i; i>0)
```

so, after breakdown,

- `run_this_once_at_start` is `i<=5&&i>=-1` <sup>Note</sup>
- `check_this_each_time` is `++i`
- `run_this_after_each_iteration` is `i>0`

which *all* are valid expressions from the *syntax* point-of-view. So, compiler's happy, no warnings.

Note: to break down `i<=5&&i>=-1`, in `C`, `<=` has higher [precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence) over `&&`, so effectively, your code behaves like `((i<=5) && (i>=-1))` which is perfectly valid.

[#] - For a detailed idea, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27398592/2173917) of mine.

Comment: Well your answer is very well explained. Thanks