# Is there some reason for this kind of for-loop?

Tags: c, for-loop, syntax

Is there some reason to write a for-loop like this in c? 
(first statement is left empty and height is set outside instead.. and that height variable is not used after this elsewhere either)

```
lastheight = halfheight;
.
. // some more code changing height, includes setting 
. // lastheight
. // to something that is essentially the height of a wall
.
height = halfheight;
for ( ; lastheight < height ; lastheight++)
```

It is referenced from [Wolfenstein3D source code](https://github.com/id-Software/wolf3d/blob/master/WOLFSRC/WOLFHACK.C#L182-183).

Comment: That's a red herring. The first line has nothing to do with the second line. What really matters is whether the `halfheight` loop variable is still used outside the loop. As it stands, a convention to only use the `for` header for the loop variable seems sensible enough.

Comment: @KerrekSB and just to add, `lastheight` initialization.

Comment: To answer the question as to why the loop variable (`lastheight`) isn't initialized in the `for` loop you need to provide enough context (i.e. the code that initializes `lastheight`). As it is phrased now this question is nonsense.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm marking this as "unclear" because you did not show how lastheight gets initialized.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I agree the question could have been rephrased, but it's not unclear. OP is confused regarding the syntax, an there is a link which actually shows the related code, isn't it?

Comment: I'm now guessing, that maybe it is just to re-use the variable?(instead of creating new inside the for () "int i=halfheight;" ) ?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I couldn't agree more, but the point really is that the `height=halfheight` line is essentially a decoy for future readers that will be more confused; probably because their C-foo isn't that strong. So I *really* think this question lacks clarity, *exactly* because of the choice of lines presented.

Comment: @mgear No, please read the code carefully. The "loop variable", if you will so, is `lastheight`, which doesn't get initialized in the two lines of code you cite. So you're not showing the relevant parts

Comment: @MarcusMüller Well, I edited the question body, does it serve better?

Comment: @KlasLindbäck point is, wolfenstein3d has an `if/else` clause before that; I'll introduce a "dummy" value for this to make sense

Comment: @SouravGhosh  I think we could agree on this comment?

Comment: So, `lastheight ` cannot be initialized in the for loop because the value is no longer available. Therefore it is initialized earlier, while the value is still available.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As long as you're bothered with the `for` loop syntax,

```
 for ( ; lastheight < height ; lastheight++)
```

is perfectly valid, as long as `lastheight` is defined and initialized previously.

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.8.5.3

> ```
> for ( clause-1 ; expression-2 ; expression-3 ) statement
> ```
>
> [...] Both *clause-1* and *expression-3* can be omitted. An omitted *expression-2* is replaced by a
>   nonzero constant.

---

Regarding the *reason* for defining `lastheight` outside the `for` loop, one thing can be mentioned, that, for a construct like

```
 for ( int lastheight = 0 ; lastheight < height ; lastheight++)  {...} //C99 and above
```

limits the *scope* of `lastheight` to the for loop body. If you want `lastheight` to be used *after* (outside the scope of) the loop body, you must have the definition outside the loop.

Also, if my memory serves correctly, before C99, declaration of a variable was not possible inside the `for` statement, anyway. So, the way to go was

```
 int lastheight;
 for ( lastheight = 0 ; lastheight < height ; lastheight++)  {...}
```

---

Also, [here's  a link to a detailed discussion about `for` loop syntax.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27398592/2173917)

<sup>*Disclaimer: My answer*.</sup>

Comment: Before C99, not only can the declaration not appear in the `for` header, but it must also appear before any other non-declaration statements. Those were dark days :-)

Answer (score 1):

Writing :

```
height = halfheight;
for ( ; lastheight < height ; lastheight++)
```

is exactly the same as :

```
for ( lastheight = halfheight; lastheight < height ; lastheight++)
```

as `lastheight = halfheight;` is your initial statement will be executed once before your loop.

---

In general, a for loop has the following structure:

```
for (part1; part2; part3) {
    ....
}
```

- **Part 1** is a statement which is *executed once, before the loop starts*. After its execution, you get into the loop and its statements start to execute. This part is mainly used for initializations useful for the loop. If you leave it empty, you simply do not do any action before the loop.
- **Part 2** is the *condition you check at each iteration*.
- **Part 3** is a statement which is e*xecuted at the end of each iteration*.

---

> height variable is not used after this elsewhere either

This is not exactly correct. Actually, it is used at the beginning of *every iteration*, as the second part of the `for` loop is evaluated at the beginning of every iteration and the loop is executed only if the condition `lastheight < height` is true.

Comment: What's with the `;;` part?

Comment: @SouravGhosh I put one extra `;` by mistake, thanks.

Comment: The first part of a `for` loop is usually used for loop variable initialization. The loop variable in this case is `lastheight`, not `height `.

Comment: @KlasLindbäck this is the usual case, but actually the first part of a `for` loop can contain ***any*** statement which will be executed once, before the loop.

Comment: You can, but that will only confuse the next guy who reads the code.