# Code not running but compiles?

Tags: c, loops, scope

I've been trying to learn C by myself for the past two days and I can't seem to get this program to run.  Sorry for this probably trivial question, just starting out and can't seem to find a quick answer.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void chopper() {
    int z = 0;
    while (z < 10) {
        printf("They equal and this code works!");
        z++;
    }
}

int main() {
    int x = 0;

    int flag = 0;

    if (flag == 1) {
        chopper();
    }
    for (int x; x < 10; x++) {
        printf("%d\n", x);
        if (x == 10) {
            flag == 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you really want to accomplish with this code?

Comment: Could you tell us what the expected input and output is? What do you mean by `not running`? Here is a guide on how to ask questions: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I am not sure how it compiles, and doesn't complain about the redeclaration of `x`.

Comment: Does it work if you add `= 0` after `int x`?

Comment: If i'm reading it correct, it's precisely what @Biffen mentioned.

Comment: Strange but given code is working here http://ideone.com/6zNL8P

Comment: @Shak; What????

Comment: FIXED!  Thanks @Biffen

Comment: You redeclare x in the loop and have to set new initial value, int x = 0 instead of int x.

Comment: Note that neither `if (flag == 1)` nor `if (x == 10)` will ever be true.

Comment: @haccks I'm just playing around with C and I couldn't figure out why this wasn't working.  Fixed now though thanks to Biffen

Comment: @Vcoss; What fixed? I can see some serious issues with the code and your understanding how it really fixed.

Comment: @Biffen Yea I was going to add something but I just ran this to make sure it still worked, it didn't and I was googling before giving up to post this

Comment: @haccks Yea it counted from 1-9 in Cmd.

Answer (score 4):

You have multiple issues.

- `flag == 1;` inside `if` is useless. Probably you meant and want `flag = 1;`.
- In the for loop, `x` is uninitialized.
- The outer scope `x` is unused.<sup>Note</sup>

What you want is to rewrite the `for` loop statement as

```
for (x; x < 10; x++)
```

or,

```
for (; x < 10; x++)
```

to make use of the outer `x` variable. As per the code shown, you don't need two separate variables anyway.

---

Note: To understand more about scope, please [refer to this previous Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37341075/2173917).